# How to create a method can read inputstream and replace new word to old word?

Tags: c#

There is a replace method that reads the InputStream and replaces the old word with a new word, then it will return the output file when I replace the word.

```
public Stream ReplaceFile(Stream InputStream, string oldword, string newword)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(InputStream);
            string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(InputStream);
            sw.Write(text.Replace(oldword, newword));


            Stream output = File.Create(@"C:\Users\users\source\test\Data\2test.csv");

            return output;       
        }
```

Comment: You can't ask questions like "is this correct?" without showing your current output or the issue that you're facing with your current code.

Comment: You asked "replace new to old" and coded "replace old to new", btw

Comment: Not sure `new StreamWriter(InputStream);` will work out.. I think the way I'd implement this is to create a stream that takes a stream in its constructor, and fills some internal buffer, performs any old word byte replacements present and emits bytes from the modified buffer. when the buffer is half depleted, it is topped up and byte replacements performed again from old word length bytes back from the end of where the buffer finished last time. Lather rinse repeat. Buffering the whole file as you're doing would make it easier but may require large amounts of memory

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835851/replacing-a-string-within-a-stream-in-c-sharp-without-overwriting-the-original - servy's answer will do if you definitely know the file contains new lines at regular intervals, otherwise Palec's answer; not for the faint hearted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome SO. In my small tests using your code, I was unable to get it work... so in my tests it is NOT correct. In addition deleting your question then reposting the same question is frowned upon and you may have problems asking new questions later if you end up deleting/reposting a bunch of questions… just a thought.

It is not clear “why” the code “passes in” a `Stream` and then returns a different `Stream`… ? … This certainly will work; however it seems unnecessary in this context. One issue you may have, is using the “same” `Stream` for both the `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` which the code appears to do. Even if the `InputStream` allows read and write access to the file… you will need to implement more code to get it to work as you are wanting. Basically, there is an easier way.

Lastly… when opening/reading/writing files… it becomes YOUR responsibility to “close” those files. It is not difficult to forget to do this and the code will never complain about it. To help, there is a statement called a “using” statement. `IF` whatever resource we want to open/read/write to implements the `IDisposable` interface… `THEN` (pardon the play on words) “using” a `using` statement will do most of what we need as far as “closing” the file or resource.

Given this, I am confident the code below should do as you are wanting. NOTE, the code does NOT take a `Stream` object nor return one. If you need this, then you may need to explain why.

Walking through the code… the method takes four (4) parameters, two `string` variables that define the source and destination file path and name. And two `string` variables that define the `oldWord` and `newWord`.

A `string text` is used to hold the text from the source file when it is read in addition to holding the same text with the replacement `newWord`.

Using a `using` statement to read the file and replace the text. Then another using statement to write the changes to a file.

I have done minor testing with this code and I am confident more error checking may be needed. Good Luck.

```
public static void ReplaceFile(String sourceFile, string destFile, string oldWord, string newWord) {
  string text;
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourceFile)) {
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    text = text.Replace(oldWord, newWord);
  }
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(destFile)) {
    sw.Write(text);
  }
}
```

Usage…

```
string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\users\source\test\Data\2test.csv";
string destPath = @"C:\Users\users\source\test\Data\2test.csv";
string oldWord = "oldWord";
string newWord = "newWord";
ReplaceFile(sourcePath, destPath, oldWord, newWord);
```